# How to send sms with sinch using a pair of ids

Tags: android, parsing, sinch

Hey guys i am an android developer and have followed the tutorials on instant messaging using sinch and parse from https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/android-messaging-tutorial-using-sinch-and-parse/.
It works quite good but i am trying to customize it a little such that i can send a message based on the recipients's id and another id . That is i want to send a message taking into consideration two ids( recipientId and another id which i defined).
Please i would appreciate any work arounds this.

Comment: You could add that id to the headers sendmessageToUserid WithHeaders

Comment: please can you elaborate further, i don't seem to follow

Comment: please i need more light on the solution to my problem, i  have been frustrated for days now

Answer (score 0):

Create a WritableMessage(List recipientUserIds, String textBody)
Constructs a message with a list of recipients and a text body.
http://download.sinch.com/docs/android/latest/reference/index.html

Comment: this make sense but my doubt is, this other id does not belong to any one. I just need it so i can be precise about where a text is going to. the other id does not really exist as a recipient id for sinch, i just created these ids to make a conversation between two people unique, such that the same parties can still be chatting but if the key is different then their conversation too is a different one.Please help me out here